# Clearing error messages in client side validations rails gem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, client-side-validation

I am using Client Side Validations rails gem v3.1.0 in my application. I have a form displayed in a jquery dialog which needs to be validated. Client state validation is enabled on that form. Everything works well with the validation, but when user cancels the dialog (without submitting), I would like to clear any existing validation errors. This way when user fires the dialog again, the validations errors are not present already on the form.

I have tried to achieve this by triggering the client state validation pass event for each element on dialog close - it works by removing the wrapping error fields and labels. One issue is that subsequent validations don't work after this code. I feel that bound events are removed and not triggered anymore.

Is there a better way of achieving this?

My jquery dialog:

```js
$('#create_dialog').dialog({
            height: 260,
            width: 420,
            title: "title",
            buttons: {"<%= I18n.t("create") %>": function(e) {
                $('#new_segment').submit();
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    var form = $('#new_segment');
                    form.find('[data-validate]:input').each(function() {
                        $(this).trigger('element:validate:pass');
                    });
                    $(this).dialog("close");

                    }
                }
        });
```

Comment: Ever get a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

not a clean way but this works

```
/**
 * Remove Embedded validation perfectly that is compatible with validation gem
 * @param field
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function removeValidationMessage(field) {
  var $field = $(field) || field;
  /**
   * First wrap the previously occurring label in wrapper div with class 'field_with_errors'
   * Then Wrap the field within a wrapper div of same class
   * Then add validation message after the field with class name 'message'
   */
  if ($field.siblings('.message').length > 0) {
    $field.parent().prev('.field_with_errors').find('label').unwrap();
    $field.unwrap();
    $field.next('.message').remove();
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/issues/328

From Brian Cardarella, developer of Client Side Validations gem:

Unfortunately right now there is not a clean way to do this. This will be changing in 4.0